# How to choose and connect graphic equalizer to adjust TV sound through external amp

Tags: speakers, television, rca, optical, equalizer

While investigating the benefits of buying a soundbar for my TV, I was advised to instead purchase a good pair of speakers and an amplifier. So I did.

I am now getting, I think, just what the sound engineers intended. However, to my ears this means too much bass, too much treble, and not enough mid-range. Consequently, especially for movies and TV drama, hearing what people say is even more difficult than it was before. So I am now investigating Graphic Equalizers...

I have three questions:

1) Is there anything I need to check to ensure maximum compatibility of an equalizer with my amp (and speakers)?

2) Input to my amp from my TV is via optical (Toslink) cable. The equalizers I have looked at during web searches seem to require RCA input*. So I'm guessing I need an optical to RCA converter...? If so, again is there anything I need to check for compatibility?

3) Will an equalizer introduce noticeable lag, ie poor lip-sync with the TV picture?

Total noob, so any other ideas gratefully received.

* eg https://www.gak.co.uk/en/behringer-minifbq-fbq800/1142

Answer (score 1):

An Optical to RCA adapter will work fine. There will not be any noticeable latency.

Just make sure your amplifier takes 1/4" or RCA input.